# Film where a boy turns into a princess

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am trying to remember a film I saw as a child where at the very end (I think), a boy who I think is the main character is turned into a princess (or maybe a queen). It turned out that he was always a princess and was transformed for some... purpose. I think it might have had to do with protecting her.

His caretakers want to transform him back, but he resists the idea at first. They eventually convince him (or he may have had no choice at all), and he transforms.

The scene is kind of bizarre and shows the character suddenly a woman wearing a flowing dress. I think the scene was outdoors in a garden.

Unfortunately this is all I remember of this movie and I am not sure reliable the details are.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As per Zeiss Ikon's answer, *[The Marvelous Land of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Marvelous_Land_of_Oz)* has a central plot point that Tip, a young boy, is actually the Princess Ozma. The film he cites, *[Return to Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Oz)*, is a partial adaptation of that book, but does not include Tip. On the other hand, *[The Wonderful Land of Oz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wonderful_Land_of_Oz)*, released in 1969, does. It is very low budget and very strange, and the transformation scene fits.

Comment: It could also be the *The Marvelous Land of Oz* stage play, also a faithful adaptation of the book, and which has had filmed versions such as at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvVxgs3dYJY.

Comment: Hard to believe how quickly the answers come in here. This is almost certainly it. The visuals are not what I had in my head, but Tip's line "but I don't want to be a girl!" plus the voice of the fairy is almost exactly what I was remembering. Accepting.

Comment: I think that the first time this story might have been filmed was Shirley Temple 's Storybook "The Land of Oz" 18 September 1960.  That is also in color, and can be seen online.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRIhwSBcGqk

Comment: I wonder if the name Tip was a tip of the hat to [Billy Tipton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billy_Tipton)... OTOH, Billy was pretty secretive about his birth gender, so I guess this is just a curious coincidence.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Probably unlikely. For one, as you note, Tipton's biological sex didn't come out until 1989. For two, Tip is short for "Tippetarius".

Comment: For three, Billy Tipton wasn't even born until seven years after the publication of *The Marvelous Land of Oz* in book form.

Comment: Wow. I've seen better productions in rural high school theater departments.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: Yeah... although at least that particular director didn't reuse clips from his nudie films. Despite the rumors, the Emerald City army was not sourced from his actresses from those films either (side note, the brief outfit is actually in common with Baum's stageplay, released as *The Woggle-Bug*, which called for said soldier girls to be played by "chorus girls").

Answer (score 15):

This sounds very much like *Return to Oz* -- this movie was based on the second and third Oz books by L. Frank Baum, and included the Deadly Desert, the Wheelmen, the witch Mombi, the Gump, as well as Dorothy and Toto and Billina the Hen -- however, Tip, who in the course of things was shown to have been Princess Ozma in the book *Ozma of Oz*, transformed into a boy and her memory blocked to keep her hidden after Mombi captured her, is bypassed and Ozma is found to be trapped in a mirror in this version.